# UICollectionViewCell unformatted in view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new to iOS development and swift but I think I'm getting the hang of it quite well.

Getting a strange bug though in my collection view. When loaded, all cells that are visible seem to not apply the constraints to implement the layout properly.  Once scrolling down, they all seem fine and when scrolling back up they have corrected themselves.

[image: uicollectioview]

Am I doing something obviously wrong to cause this?

Comment: Try calling `collectionView.layoutSubviews` in your `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: That works great for the first page but as soon as I swipe right, it has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry meant to tag @EmilioPelaez

Comment: What's the hierarchy of your view controllers?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I have a page view controller linked to a navigation controller. The collectionview controller is rendered for each page in the page view controller. Sorry if  the terminology is wrong ;)

Comment: Try calling `layoutSubviews` on the `collectionView` every time you return the view controller from the `UIPageViewController` data source method.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez genius. That solved it. Many thanks!